# Where did python3.4 download to on my mac?

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenv

I decided today I better download python 3.4. So I go to the python/downloads page and do that. Now I am trying to make a new virtualenv using my new python module,  `mkvirtualenv -p python3.4 sandbox`, but I get an error that it can't find my python executable.

```
The executable /Users/croberts/python3.4 (from --python=/Users/croberts/python3.4) does not exist
```

This is understandable, but I can't figure out where it is. The old versions of python are in /usr/bin/ but the new one didn't get installed there. How do you search for where a program is using the terminal?

Comment: Does OSX have `which` built into it? On Linux, I would just use `which python3.4`.

Comment: `which` is indeed present on OSX. Typically it'll be somewhere like `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ReadMe.txt bundled with the installer, Python installs default to `/Library/frameworks/Python.framework`. I just did a test install and it ended up here specifically:

```
/Library/frameworks/Python.framework/versions/3.4/Python
```

Unless you changed the settings on the installer, that's where it should live. (If you installed it from source, I'd assume you'd know where you put it.) Something to note is that if you use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (and possibly other OSX package managers like MacPorts, though I haven't used it), installing Python through the PPC installer will cause a warning:

```
Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.
```

So if you do use Homebrew (and it's great), it's best to simply use `brew install python3`, which will put it into `/usr/local/bin`. Then you can alias `python` (or `python3`) to that version, instead.